# onclose, onmessage, onerror callback overloading Websocket Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket

I am working on a Typescript Websocket Project, where the client connects to Backend using Websocket connections.
So obviously typescript will give type hints about the Websocket and its `on` callbacks like, onclose, onmessage, etc.

Take `onmessage` now. `onmessage` type signature is `(this: WebSocket, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any` (I just directly copied from vscode hints).

So first parameter is `this` of type `WebSocket`, i.e that same instance.
Second parameter is `ev` of type `MessageEvent`.

If I need the `MessageEvent`, I should pass the function as

```
ws.onmessage = function (this: WebSocket, ev: MessageEvent<any>) {
  console.log("Event", ev);
}
```

Yes, as expected above code works.

But, the below code also works.

```
ws.onmessage = function (ev: MessageEvent<any>) {
  console.log("Event", ev);
}
```

Even the Typescript is getting compiled to JS, so there is no way there can be any kind of method overloading happened in this case. (Like in JAVA).

How `onmessage` knows to pass the event to my function:

- as second param when there are two params.
- as first param when there is one param.

Comment: `this:` isn't treated as a function argument, since `this` is a reserved keyword (you can't have a variable/function argument named `this`) so `this:` is treated as a declaration of what `this` is expected to be, that is all - your function is always called with one argument

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right, I am getting a type error If I rename the `this` variable to something else. Or If I change it to arrow function.

I̶ ̶d̶i̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶h̶a̶v̶i̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶.̶ ̶I̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶g̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶?̶

Oh so WebSocket only calls it with one argument, but because of the declaration it gets the this as first parameter.

I see it as same behavior as Python's `self`. Is this behavior can be reproduced in other languages other than js and python?

Comment: it's not a behaviour of functions, it's a feature of typescript - `because of the declaration it gets the this as first parameter` no, it's not because of the declaration, it gets the `this` it gets because that's how **java**script works - that syntax is just a way to tell typescript what "type" of thing `this` will be

Comment: lot's of languages have a `this` ... how it works varies from language to language, but, to re-iterate, declaring what `this` is in typescript has no effect at all on what `this` will be - it will be what it is, you're just telling typescript what it will be, not what to make it

Comment: You are right, I have confirmed by trying it out in dev console.
This was new for me. Thank you!

Comment: how does one confirm typescript cruft "in dev console"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't elaborated.
I confirmed it was not a javascript feature, as Dev Tools throws an Error when I try to use this in function param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of Typescript. [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function).

The `this` from the first param will be stripped during transpiling.
You can see the transpiling using [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHNCBfQwmAVxATGAD2IZEwhgAQhDhQAFGAAWwWjXRZcASmQqM2PEVLIFSgHTlKyALzIARIuvFkASARDaAnBGM4BTOYtrqDiRQYlxQwka0bBwuIG4eXj4yohJSUMYIuDgy-GQU1DaQ9NbIrOqm-epAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2%2Ctypescript&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.23.6&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D). So the onmessage callback wont know if the function has two or one param.

Note: `this` in function param throws an error.

Comment: I removed my name from this answer as it is fundamentally wrong - read what I wrote, not what you think I wrote